# BLE Connection not pairing

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS app that works on iOS 14 on all of my test devices, iPhone XR, iPhone 11 Max, iPhone 7.  The app connects to a BLE device, the app reads and sends settings over Bluetooth to modify the devices behavior.

I just got a new phone (iPhone 13 Pro) and I was doing some final testing before release.  So this is the first time this app is running on this phone.  I *never* get the dialog to pop up that asks to pair the device when I connect to it.  I thought this was strange.  So I went back to my iPhone XR and "forgot" the BLE device.  I delete the app and re-run.  It sees the device, I hit connect in the app and it asks me if I would like to pair.

Obviously this is some weird exception I am not handling quite right.  Does anyone have a thought?  Looking around here on Stackoverflow and google and I don't see that anyone else has run into this.

This is an objective-c app, using CoreBluetooth.

Comment: For pairing with a BLE device, you need to try reading a characteristic which is encrypted, this will trigger the pairing pop-up. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  And on the older devices, this is the behavior I am seeing.  But if I run the app on the 13 Pro with iOS 15.2, the dialog never appears when performing the read.